# Slice Large GeoTiff into 1 Degree Tiles

Tags: tile, gdal, geotiff

I have a bunch of large GeoTiff files (1.4GB, 4 latitude degrees x 8 longitude degrees).

I need to slice each one up into 1 degree lat x 1 degree long tiles (with just a little bit of overage in each).

Here is the gdalinfo output for one of the GeoTiff files:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: index.tif
Size is 38401, 19201
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-112.000104166666674,56.000104166666667)
Pixel Size = (0.000208333333333,-0.000208333333333)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-112.0001042,  56.0001042) (112d 0' 0.38"W, 56d 0' 0.37"N)
Lower Left  (-112.0001042,  51.9998958) (112d 0' 0.38"W, 51d59'59.62"N)
Upper Right (-103.9998958,  56.0001042) (103d59'59.62"W, 56d 0' 0.37"N)
Lower Right (-103.9998958,  51.9998958) (103d59'59.62"W, 51d59'59.62"N)
Center      (-108.0000000,  54.0000000) (108d 0' 0.00"W, 54d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=38401x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32767
```

I want everything to be the same except the size.  So each one needs to be sliced into 32 tiles, each 1 degree x 1 degree.

For instance one would cover:
-112.0001042, 56.0001042 to -110.9998958, 54.9998958 (essentially -112, 56 to -111, 55).

I see utilities like gdal_retile.py and gdal_grid, but I'm not making progress.  What is the right tool / command line options for this?

Comment: Have a look at `gdal_translate`, especially the `projwin` keyword:
http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

Answer (score 3):

You could use gdal_translate in a Python loop as below:

```py
import os

for ulx in range(-112,-103):
    for uly in range(51,56):
        os.system('gdal_translate -projwin '+str(ulx)+' '+str(uly)+' '+str(ulx+1)+' '+str(uly+1)+' index.tif index_tile_ulx_'+str(ulx)+'_uly_'+str(uly)+'.tif')
```